# Prestashop Create Order API

Tags: api, prestashop

i try to create an API connection so i can create orders in Prestashop via API,
in their DOC:
http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/720902/CRUD+Tutorial+EN.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1301486324000

there is no information about creating orders, and when i try to create something myself everything fails:

```
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => 'http://mysite.com/prestashop/api/orders?schema=synopsis'));

$resources = $xml -> children() -> children();
$resources->children()->id_address_delivery = 1;
$resources->children()->id_address_invoice = 1;
$resources->children()->id_cart = 1;
$resources->children()->id_currency = 1;
$resources->children()->id_lang = 2;
$resources->children()->id_customer = 1;
$resources->children()->id_carrier = 2;
$resources->children()->total_paid = '1';
$resources->children()->total_paid_real = '1';
$resources->children()->total_products = 1;
$resources->children()->total_products_wt = 1;
$resources->children()->conversion_rate = 0.1;

$resources->children()->module = 'cheque';
$resources->children()->payment = 'Cheque';

$xml = $webService->add(array('resource' => 'orders',
'postXml' => $resources->asXML()
));
```

Gives errors etc, does somebody here has proper documentation available? Or a script which runs in making simple orders?

Comment: Indeed, a good question, especially since Prestashop does not provide any samples/docs for creating new orders/carts. What is the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create order with PrestaShop's API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106680/create-order-with-prestashops-api)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the schema then foreach the lines returned, or just supply the values manually.

here is a sample of getting the schema of the selected method.

```
$xml = $webService -> 
  get(array('url' => 'http://mysite.com/prestashop/api/customers?schema=blank'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **Customer**, **Address**, **Cart** and finally **Order**. And before creating an order you must have products in the cart and must set id_address_delivery & id_address_invoice.

You can read more details on my blog [PrestaShop web service create order errors](http://www.exploreroute.com/prestashop-webservice-create-order-errors/)